# Accessing enum members from class

Tags: c++

So consider this struct:

```cpp
struct CType
{
    enum DType
    {
        Int,
        Char
    } Type;

    union Value
    {
        int num;
        char alpha;

        Value() {
            this->num = 0;
            this->alpha = '\0';
        };
        ~Value() {};
    } value;
};
```

How can I do this?

```cpp
CType u3;
u3.Type = CType::Int;
```

Why does the above work?

I would have done it this way:

```cpp
u3.Type = CType::DType::Int;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside: `Value::Value()` only needs to initialise one of `num` and `alpha`. Consider using `using CType = std::variant<int, char>;` instead of all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DType` is an Unscoped Enumeration that is visible in its enclosing scope:

**Unscoped Enumeration** (emphasis mine) - pre-C++11:

> Each enumerator becomes a named constant of the enumeration's type (that is, name), **visible in the enclosing scope**, and can be used whenever constants are required.

You're looking for **Scoped Enumeration** (available since C++11):

> Each enumerator becomes a named constant of the enumeration's type (that is, name), **which is contained within the scope of the enumeration, and can be accessed using scope resolution operator**. There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types, although static_cast may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

See documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

So, the `DType` as a Scoped Enumeration would be:

```
enum class DType { Int, Char };
```

and, `Int` from it can be accessed like this:

```
DType::Int
```

Answer (score 2):

Historically, that is how enum works.

Write "enum class" instead of "enum" and you get increased safety and the access syntax that you want.

Comment: Why did they modify its behavior? And how is that possible?

Comment: I can point you to this [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum), but keep in mind that some things have changed since then.